# How to remove outiers from multi columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to get a data frame that contains only data that is within 2 SD per each numeric column.
I know how to do it for a single column but how can I do it for a bunch of columns at once?
Here is the toy data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = "target birds    wolfs     Country
                                3       21         7 a
                                3        8         4 b
                                1        2         8 c
                                1        2         3 a
                                1        8         3 a
                                6        1         2 a
                                6        7         1 b
                                6        1         5 c",header = TRUE)
```

Here is the code line for getting only the data that is under 2 SD for a single column(birds).How can I do it for all numeric columns at once?

```
df[!(abs(df$birds - mean(df$birds))/sd(df$birds)) > 2,]
  target birds wolfs Country
2      3     8     4       b
3      1     2     8       c
4      1     2     3       a
5      1     8     3       a
6      6     1     2       a
7      6     7     1       b
8      6     1     5       c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the dataset columns and subset the `numeric` vectors (by using a `if/else` condition) based on the `mean` and `sd`.

```
lapply(df, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x[!(abs((x-mean(x))/sd(x))>2)] else x)
```

EDIT:

I was under the impression that we need to remove the outliers for each column separately.  But, if we need to keep only the rows that have no outliers for the numeric columns, we can loop through the columns with `lapply` as before, instead of returning 'x', we return the sequence of 'x' and then get the `intersect` of the `list` element with `Reduce`.  The numeric index can be used for subsetting the rows.

```
lst <- lapply(df, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) 
        seq_along(x)[!(abs((x-mean(x))/sd(x))>2)] else seq_along(x))

df[Reduce(intersect,lst),]
```

Comment: Hello @akrun, I tried your code but i get a list.I didn't find a way to transfrom it to a data frame.Can you elaborate?

Comment: @mql4beginner  I was away, just updated the post.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun..Nice to get familiar with Reduce and intersect functions.

Comment: @mql4beginner  No problem.  Glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that you are trying to filter your data set by checking that *all* of the numeric columns are within 2 SD (?)

In that case I would suggest to create two filters. 1 one that will indicate numeric columns, the second one that will check that all of them within 2 SD. For the second condition, we can use the built in `scale` function

```
indx <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
indx2 <- rowSums(abs(scale(df[indx])) <= 2) == sum(indx)
df[indx2,]
#   target birds wolfs Country
# 2      3     8     4       b
# 3      1     2     8       c
# 4      1     2     3       a
# 5      1     8     3       a
# 6      6     1     2       a
# 7      6     7     1       b
# 8      6     1     5       c
```

Comment: Thanks @David Arenburg,Your solution works, but I don't understand how rowSums can be used to to answer my questions about columns?

Comment: What is your question exactly? `rowSums` just filters by condition that *all* the values in a certain row are under 2 SD of their column.

Comment: What's your desired output exactly?

Comment: A data frame without the the rows that have > 2SD values per column.As you did.

Comment: Hey @David Arenburg, your solution is great too.I tried to do use this structure to another calculation and failed with it while in the other answer I was able to use it to the same task which was replacing the condition to include all rows that are below the 0.95 quantile.  I agree that your solution is more easy to write and execute..